# Exclude element from zooming using SvgPanZoom

Tags: svgpanzoom

I have an SVG and in it a lot of elements. I also have a popup element which is shown on an element click. When I zoom the SVG the popup should not be zoomed. How can I prevent this popup from being zoomed with the SVG?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [this demo](http://ariutta.github.io/svg-pan-zoom/demo/layers.html). Basically you can zoom only one SVG group while keeping others static.